# How does the $\beta$ factor appear in eq. (4.33) of Altland, Simons "Condensed Matter Field Theory"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, dimensional-analysis, many-body

In Altland and Simons' "Condensed Matter Field Theory" book, on the partition function for the non-interacting gas section, is states:

[image]

however, immediately after that, a beta factor shows up when computing the Path Integral:

[image]

where $\zeta =1 (−1)$ for bosonic (fermionic) ﬁelds, respectively.

Where is that $\beta$ factor coming from?

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of screenshots/images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors of $\beta$ can be somewhat slippery in the Matsubara formualism. The change of variables from $\phi(\tau)$ to $\phi_n$ produces an extra factor of $\beta$ for each $n$ in the Jacobian. See footnote 9 on the preceding page (168).